# PyTube playlist downloding giving output of 1 and not downloading the videos (syntax is written according to the documentation)

Tags: python

```
from pytube import Playlist

vid_num = 0
playlist_url = Playlist("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7yh-TELLS1GmTcE9tLKsrQ5iCAtnLAc1")

for video in playlist_url.videos:
vid_num += 1
print("Downloading {}......".format(vid_num))
video.streams.get_by_itag(22).download()
```

After running this code I get an output of 1 and nothing downloads, even the code is correct is same as the documentation. Can anyone please tell me why is this happening.

Answer (score 1):

There is (was) an issue with the `pytube` library, which was fixed in a PR related to this [issue](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/848) and [this one](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/pull/860) where a local fix is suggested.

The package is not updated with this latest PR on pypi yet, so you need to uninstall the currently installed one and re-install it from the official git repository like this:

```
sudo -H pip3 install git+https://github.com/nficano/pytube
```

Comment: If the issue is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted to close it. @RudraPatel